# Read a .txt file from a certain LINE onwards with PHP

Tags: php

I know there might be many questions related to this one but I read most of them and still got no idea on how to do this.

Suppose I have a certain **.txt file with each line being part of a chat log**.

What I'd like to do is retrieve lines of the file, from line ***x*** *onwards* to the end. So if I have ***x* = 450** I'd like to obtain the lines **450->eof()**. I've tried this with [stream_get_line](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-line.php) and other  functions but I always get stuck at *"number of bytes to read"* from file. How am I even suppose to know the number of bytes a line occupies, being them all different from each other?

Each line separates by **\n** and the files might have **+500.000** lines.

Then I'd need to process each extracted line and I take it from here...

Here is a *schema*

```
if(file_exists($file)){
     $x = 500; //hard-coded
$file = fopen($file);
$single_line_or_could_be_all_at_once(exploded) = stream_get_line($file,$x,"\n"); //nope.
//process lines
}
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. You have to go line by line BECAUSE you don't know how much information is on one line.

Comment: You want to use [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php). You can omit the length parameter.

Comment: @thatidiotguy even if each line is separated by "\n" and it's assured there is no "\n" in the middle of the content?

Comment: @user3385828 Computers don't store things by "lines".  That's a human construct.

Answer (score 2):

Since each line is of variable width, the only way to do this is to read from the beginning of the file, skipping over the first N lines that you don't need.

My PHP is very rusty, but it would go something like this (and feel free to edit the code to correct any syntax errors)

```
$lineNr = 1;
$in = fopen('file.txt', 'rb');
while($line = fread($in)) {
    if ($lineNr >= 450) { 
       // Use the line
    }
    $lineNr++;
}
```

If you want, you can modify the `while` to end when either the end of the file is reached, or a maximum line number desired is reached, like:

```
while($line = fread($in) && $lineNr < 550) {
```